# Where should i put my ef model files

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am working on an asp.net core mvc 2.0 web application.
This application works with an sql server database and entity framework core.
I want to create a console project for doing some batch stuff at night. This project should access the same database than the web project.
So i decided to create a third common project (library) which will contains models classes, db context and migrations.
The 2 project will reference this common project.

When i try to run "dotnet ef" commands in the terminal, in the common project subfolder, i get an error saying me this project should be startup project. But this is a shared library ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF Core differs from EF in that the context is designed to be instantiated via a dependency injection container. In other words, it relies on a `DbContextOptions` instance being injected that tells it among other things what type of database connection to use and how to connect. Since this injection only occurs inside projects that actually *run* (i.e. not a class library), the EF command-line tools only work by default with "startup projects", i.e. projects that can actually be started.

To enable migrating against a class library, EF Core provides `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`. The EF commands will look for an implementation of this interface, and if it exists, use that factory to create the context it needs. As a result, you simply need to create an implementation in your class library.

```
public class MyContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyContext>
{
    public MyContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("[connection string here]");

        return new MyContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Yes, this means you need to hard-code your connection string, but importantly this is not environment-specific. More appropriately, the only environment you should be migrating in is development, so you don't *need* it to be environment-specific.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation)